# Copy values based on criteria with macro

Tags: excel, vba, copy, criteria

I have 2 columns, one with dates (column A:A, of type dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm) the other with values of a parameter (column B:B), registered at each date. But not all dates have registered values (in which case in column B I will have -9999.

What I need is to copy to other columns (say D:D and E:E) only the cells where there is a value other than -9999 and the correspondent date too. For example:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47ZYM.gif)
[image]

My data series is pretty long, it can get to 10000 or more lines, so I cannot do this selection “manually”. I would prefer macros, not array formulae, because I want to choose the moment of the calculation.

Comment: Look at the [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx). If you run into trouble, come back and edit your question to show what you've come up with (working or not). Along with your code, include some sample data that [does not have to be retyped from an image](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Comment: See [Copy multiple Range from Sheet1 based on a conditionand paste it in Alongside in Sheet2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/47ZYM.gif).

Comment: Thank you for telling me I should not post images! Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should do what you are looking for. This will copy all rows with a value in column B, into columns D and E.'

```
Sub copyrows()
Dim RowNo, newRowNo As Long

    RowNo = 2
    newRowNo = 2

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

      .Cells(1, 4).Value = "Date"
      .Cells(1, 5).Value = "H_Selected"

          Do Until .Cells(RowNo, 1) = ""

             If .Cells(RowNo, 2) <> "-9999" Then
               .Cells(newRowNo, 4) = .Cells(RowNo, 1)
               .Cells(newRowNo, 5) = .Cells(RowNo, 2)
               newRowNo = newRowNo + 1
             End If

          RowNo = RowNo + 1

          Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I needed!